# What are the exact color spaces of DXGI_FORMATs?

Tags: graphics, game-engine, direct3d, color-space, dxgi

In the official documentation of DXGI_FORMAT, it tells us that only a format with _SRGB enumeration postfix is in sRGB color space. I thought other format without this postfix are all in the linear space. But I found a very strange behavior of format conversion function in DirectXTex library. ( You can download it from http://directxtex.codeplex.com/ )

At first, I exported a texture file as DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT by using NVIDIA Photoshop DDS Plugin. Then I load this file by LoadFromDDSFile() function, and convert its format to DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM by Convert() function. (Both of these two functions are provided by DirectXTex library.)

You guess what? After the image was converted to DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM, the brightness of all pixels were also changed, the whole image becomes brighter than before.

If I manually convert the pixel values from sRGB space to Linear space after the image was converted to DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM format, the resultant pixel values are same as input. Therefore, I suppose that the DirectXTex library treats DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT as a format in linear color space, and treats DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM as a format in sRGB color space, then it did the color space transforming from linear space to sRGB space. ( I tried to find out why the Convert() function also converts the color space, but it was implemented by WIC, and there is no source code for it. )

So, is there any bug in DirectXTex library? Or is it the real standard for DXGI_FORMATs? If there were different color spaces for some special DXGI_FORMATs, please tell me that where can I find the specification for it.

Any help will be grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convention float RGB values are linear, and integer RGB values are gamma-compressed.  There is no particular benefit to gamma-compressing floats since the reason for gamma is to use more bits where it is perceptually needed, and floats have sufficient (perhaps excessive) number of bits throughout *and* are already pseudo-log encoded (using the exponent).  ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction))

Note that the colorspace of integer RGB textures in DXGI which are not specifically *_SRGB is not sRGB, it is driver dependent, and usually has a fixed gamma of 0.5.

The DirectXTex library does appear to be behaving correctly.  However, please note that you are also relying on the behavior of whatever software you use to both capture and display the DDS files.  A better test for just DirectXTex is simply to do a round-trip conversion float->int->float in the library and compare the results numerically rather than visually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really helped me. But I still have one question: you said that the integer RGB values are commonly gamma-compressed, and DXGI formats with _SRGB have a fixed gamma of 0.5. So what's the different between these two? Are their gammas equal? Or maybe the _SRGB only means that its value need to be converted by hardware? Thank you!

Comment: Hello SeaStar, sRGB has a more complicated form of gamma, which is not a single number.  I said that DXGI formats which are integers but do *not* have a _SRGB suffix have a fixed gamma, which is *probably* 0.5.  The formats that have a _SRGB suffix are supposed to be sRGB, and therefore have the complicated gamma.  More info: "Unlike most other RGB color spaces, the sRGB gamma cannot be expressed as a single numerical value." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB  Hope that helps!

Comment: I typed a wrong word in my previous comment, I want to say that ” DXGI formats with _SRGB have **not** a fixed gamma of 0.5.” And I did more research on it today.

Comment: According to the data conversion rules of DXGI format ( you can find it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd607323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ), gamma correction or inversed operation are only performed when converting between SRGB format and float format. ( Maybe also between integer format and SRGB format ) And it uses exact sRGB conversion formula you mentioned above. So DirectXTex library (or should we blame WIC instead?) indeed acts oddly, or doesn't follow the standard at least.

Comment: I also calculated the correct gamma value which was used by DirectXTex library to convert from ARGB32F to ARGB16UNORM by comparing the output value and original value, it's about 2.2764, not 2.0 or 2.2 as usual.

Well, for me now, I just want to convert it back to linear space with correct gamma value and continue my work. Thank you again. And I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: It describes more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh972627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx